# Can't overlap more than one image on another?

Tags: css

I want to have my three images on my page overlaped over another and then make `shadow-box` on the ones that are overlapping. The first image (.hem) is overlapping the second one (.sol) but I can't get (.sol) to overlap (.vatten). Heres my css.

```
    #projekt {
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    }
    .hem {
    width: 28%;
    position: relative;
    margin-left:  -65px;
    }
    .sol {
    width: 23%;
    margin-left: -35px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    }
    .vatten {
    width: 23%;
    margin-left: -65px;
    margin-bottom: 75px;
    }
```

(#projekt) is just the div for my under classes.

Heres the Html:

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post the HTML as well so we can help you. Try looking into `z-index`. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Try to work with z-index :)

Comment: It worked! forgot to position the classes:/ thanks!